# How to retrieve only the first 2 data from a specific REST endpoint (no the entire data) Python

Tags: rest

How to retrieve only the first 2 data from a specific REST endpoint

In my example below:

Hide   Copy Code
only contains 2 records within the blobJson string.

where my output:

```
[
 {
  "sensorClass": 101, 
  "uID": "flgSh9oHnutzvZVOnnixFNjXIda2zula_101_101", 
  "eventCode": 101, 
  "sensorUUID": "flgSh9oHnutzvZVOnnixFNjXIda2zula", 
  "timeStamp": 1.594297110372e+18, 
  "deviceMfg": 101, 
  "blobJson": "[{'deviceTimestamp': 166150, 'x': 3.8919, 'y': -8.6865, 'z': -3.3077}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166170, 'x': 4.2998, 'y': -9.8624, 'z': -2.0769}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166190, 'x': 0.74341, 'y': -9.4483, 'z': 0.57692}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166210, 'x': 0.73178, 'y': -9.5004, 'z': 3.0769}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166230, 'x': 3.5538, 'y': -9.7006, 'z': 3.3077}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166250, 'x': -1.4629, 'y': -7.0692, 'z': 2.2308}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166260, 'x': -6.7571, 'y': -5.0299, 'z': -0.076923}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166280, 'x': -5.0319, 'y': -6.5896, 'z': -0.076923}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166300, 'x': -0.21122, 'y': -8.9002, 'z': 2.5}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166320, 'x': 6.3477, 'y': -9.3142, 'z': 4.5385}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166340, 'x': 10.904, 'y': -9.9498, 'z': 5.6538}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166360, 'x': 9.5501, ......
```

I had tried below:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://ws1.chic.ulster.ac.uk/SensorCentral/REST/SensorDataRangeNanos/flgSh9oHnutzvZVOnnixFNjXIda2zula_101_101?startTs=1594297110372000000&endTs=1594297110372000000"

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
parsed = json.loads(data)

print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=1))
```

Note that this only contains 2 records within the blobJson string.
[image]

I want my output as:

```
[
 {
  "sensorClass": 101, 
  "uID": "flgSh9oHnutzvZVOnnixFNjXIda2zula_101_101", 
  "eventCode": 101, 
  "sensorUUID": "flgSh9oHnutzvZVOnnixFNjXIda2zula", 
  "timeStamp": 1.594297110372e+18, 
  "deviceMfg": 101, 
  "blobJson": "[{'deviceTimestamp': 166150, 'x': 3.8919, 'y': -8.6865, 'z': -3.3077}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166170, 'x': 4.2998, 'y': -9.8624, 'z': -2.0769}]"
 }
]
```

Comment: Can you check whether my understanding of your question is correct, You are doing a list query and you want only two elements to be returned ? And one element of the list equals the complete element you shown with uuid `flgSh9oHnutzvZVOnnixFNjXIda2zula_101_101`. Or do you want that your result show show only two blobJson ?

Comment: The question needs more clarity.

Comment: @DeepakPatankar, Thanks. I want the output like I listed and 2 of element in blobJson.

Comment: @SaikrishnaRadarapu Sorry, I had editted my questions.

Comment: Do you want to get first two elements of "blobJson"??

Comment: @SaikrishnaRadarapu, yes, correct. `print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=1))`